# What are some examples of free software that could generate custom TTS voices based on recordings?

Tags: speech-synthesis

I am looking for free software with which I could record samples of my voice, plug them in to the software, and have the software either

1. output a SAPI 4 or 5 voicebank I could use with Balabolka (a free TTS), or
2. use said bank to output audio files of text I type in.

I don't care whether it's AI or not, though some degree of voice intonation would be nice, and the large number of recordings needed for a non-AI bank does not scare me, I've recorded UTAU voicebanks before. I just need a way to make my own voice into a TTS that I can use.

I would prefer not to have to do any coding to make it work (besides formatting text for intonation or pauses), but if that's the only way, I understand, and would like some information on how to do it.